# patch with fieldname parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

strange behaviour
oninit event im patching value to field
and the value not updated in the form
but if I put the field name text directly inside the json , it's working

/*not work*/
`let paramx = "fieldname";     this.form.patchValue({paramx: "77"});`

work
 `this.form.patchValue({"fieldname": "77"});`

Answer (score 0):

With the way object declarations work in JavaScript, `{ paramx:`  is identical to `{ "paramx":` . You need to actually interpolate the variable in the object definition.

You can do this in a few ways, but the simplest which should be supported is to use brackets:

```
{ [paramx]: "77" }
```

You can also create a new object and set the property using brackets. This will work in very old versions of JavaScript too:

```
const properties = {};
properties[paramx] = "77";
```